# Access 64 bit ODBC

Tags: odbc, ms-access-2013

I think I already know the answer to this question, but I would like confirmation either way.  I have Office 2013 64 bit installed and I can connect to Oracle with a DSN created in the 64 bit ODBC, is it possible to link a table using a 32 bit ODBC dsn?  When I try to re-link the table the only available DSN's in the Select Datasource box are 64 bit ones.

My issue is that there are some databases that will be used by users on both 32 and 64 bit windows machines so it would seem the only way is to create dsn's on 64 bit machines using the same drivers as the 32 bit, by way of example the SQL DSN is a SQL Native Client (with the same name) and I have installed the 64 bit version of this and this works on both 32 bit and 64 bit.  However I only have the 32 bit Oracle 11 drivers, would I therefore require a 64 bit version of this in order to link to these tables in Access 2013 64 bit?

I hope this isn't too confusing, but any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

A 64-bit application will only be able to use 64-bit ODBC data sources. Similarly, a 32-bit application will only be able to use 32-bit ODBC data sources.

If you only have a 32-bit version of a particular ODBC driver then your application will have to be running as 32-bit in order to use it. In the case of an Access application, that means running it using the 32-bit version of Access.